# Using "where" to limit template to non-bool struct types

Tags: c#

I'm writing a template that is valid for all basic types except bool.
Specifically it is writing to the BinaryWriter which does not support Write(bool).

```
public void Write<T>(T val) where T : struct
{
    if (binWriter != null)
    {
        binWriter.Write(val);
    }
}
```

The C# compiler gives me the error:

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(bool)' has some invalid arguments
```

Which I assume I could get rid of if I could use `where` to limit the template to non-bool values. Is there anyway to do this? Or is there another solution that will workaround this limitation?

Comment: `BinaryWriter.Write` does have an overload for `bool`. Regarding your question, no there's no way to do this. Also be aware that C# generics are quite different from C++ templates, and you won't get the calls to `Write` specialised for each concrete type you provide to calls of `Write`.

Comment: There is no constraint you can place upon `T` that will limit it to "things that are not bools". [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) is the list of permissible constrains.

Comment: I would bite the bullet and just write a overload for `Write` that implements each type that `binWriter.Write` supports. 5 minutes at most with a little copy and pasting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not do what you think it does.  The compiler is trying to bind `binWriter.Write` to one of the [available overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Since `object` is the only common base class in your type restriction and there's no overload that takes an `object`, the compiler can't bind to an overload and picks one (the first one alphabetically, I'm guessing) to show you in the error message.

You *could* use `dynamic` instead of generics and bind at run-time:

```
public void Write(dynamic val) 
{
    if (binWriter != null)
    {
        binWriter.Write(val);
    }
}
```

Which would fail at run-time if you try to use a type that does not have an appropriate overload.

Another alternative is to determine the type and bind to the appropriate overload:

```
public void Write<T>(T val) where T : struct
{
    if (binWriter != null)
    {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(bool)
            binWriter.Write((bool)val);
        else if(typeof(T) == typeof(byte)
            binWriter.Write((byte)val);

        ..etc
    }
}
```

But then the use of generics is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not.

You can provide a base class, interface or some other constraints (take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx), but you cannot exclude a type, especially a primitive one.

I'd suggest using some conversion mechanisms instead (if they are needed - according to @Lee's comment there is an overload for that).